# Hibernate: merge with many-to-many results in StackOverflowError

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, merge, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship were the link table has an additional field. Hence the relationship is done with 2 one-to-many relations according to below tutorial:

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/comment-page-1/#comment-122181

I have the 2 entities, a third entity which defined the link table and consist of an @Embeddable ID field.

The relationship is defined as:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.compound", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.structure", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

were pk = the @Embeddable ID field. Insert and deleting works fine however when I call

```
session.merge(compound);
```

I get a StackOverflowError and log shows that hibernate is making tons of select statements. Note that database contains exactly 1 association, eg. 1 compound containing 2 structures. It looks like hibernate gets into a endless loop.

I've seen this solution also on http://giannigar.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/mapping-a-many-to-many-join-table-with-extra-column-using-jpa/ but how do you do updated with this?

Comment: Maybe you are loading your complete many-to-many tables via the many-to-many relation. Imagine `A1` references `B1`. `B1` references `A1` and `A2`. `A2` references `B2`. And so on. With every switch from one side of the relationship to the other, you get an additional stack level.

Comment: Persist and load works but when calling merge the issue appears.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker, nevertheless merge should manage the entities visited by an earlier merge sub-operation.

beginner_ would you please share your complete entities with a test case so we can better help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution was to use FetctType.EAGER on the owning side and FetchType.Lazy on child side and in the 2 ManyToOne relations in the link table. Like this I can load from the owning side without getting LazyInitializationException and mergign working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I second SpaceTuckker's answer. I don't think Persist is the same as merge. Merge will load the object before persisting it. Persist doesn't. So when you call merge IMHO it needs to load the lazy relation. If you call persist it does not.

You might also use @ElementDependent to mark related @OneToMany relations as depending on another table. This was the way I solved the Many-To-Many relation with additional columns in the join table.

Comment: Yeah but getting the entity works. So I can persist and in a completely different session load it and no issue. The issue only occurs on merge. The solution turned out to be to add fetch = FetchType.LAZY to the ManyToOne relations in the Embeddable ID class.